# Variable not updating with fetch response data in Angular 2 beta

Tags: angular

I have been trying to update a variable with the fetch response data in order to bind the same for ng-For directive in my template. I am getting the response and see it in console, but it does not update the variable in my codes.

getStoreList is the function I am calling on click event. 
this.stores is the variable I want to update with response data.

Any help in this regard is appreciated. Thanks.

```
getStoreList:function(val){
var str='{"title":"'+val+'"}';

    fetch('http://localhost:3000/mystorelist/getstores', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
      },
      body:str
    })
    .then(function(response){
        response.json().then(function(data) { 

            this.stores=data[0].stores;


            //localStorage.setItem('storelist',JSON.stringify(this.stores))

      });

    })

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` won't refer to your class because it's nested inside those callbacks. You can use the es6 arrow function to help out.

```
.then((response) => {
    response.json().then((data) => { 
        this.stores=data[0].stores;
  });
})
```

The arrow function makes the `this` of a function refer to the same `this` of the parent function.